# How to tittle a bold roman letter at a plot

Tags: r, plot

I'm having difficulties tittling my plot in bold font roman letters. I've made a couple of tries, but the less idiotic ones are shown above:

```
# error
plot(1)
title(main=bquote(paste("Title ",.(bold(as.roman(i))))) ,family = "Computer Modern", adj = 0)

# not pretty
title(main=expression(paste("Title ",bold(as.roman(i)))) ,family = "Computer Modern", adj = 0)
```

I've tried to replace `bquote` to `expression` & `substitute`, suggestions from others similar questions posted in *SO*, but without success.

Comment: @MarcoSandri, this changes the whole font type, not just the roman

Comment: `as.roman` would just convert your integer or your letter to the corresponding roman letter right ? Or am I missing something ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just want the roman numeral to be bold:

```
plot(1)
text <- as.character(as.roman(4))
title(main = bquote(Title~bold(.(text))))
```

[image]